# Map docker container to regular dev domain name

Tags: php, nginx, docker, dns, hosts

I'm new to docker, and have recently installed a docker container/image using the phpdocker.io (php7, nginx, mysql) generator. Started it using docker-compose and it's working awesome.

If I go to localhost/phpinfo.php my regular system php version loads (5.6), if I go to localhost:**8080**/phpinfo.php my docker php version loads (7.0) so it's working ok.

My question is: There is any way to map my localhost:8080 to a regular domain name like I normally do with my regular localhost projects? Withouth having to use localhost:8080 i.e.: myproject.dev

Not sure if this is specifically docker related or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is easy.  if your nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
   server_name _; #catch all
   ...
```

you can add to hosts file on you host machine the line

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
```

and your container will be available by url `http://myproject.dev:<exposed_port>`

if you expose you container on 80 port, you can simply type url `http://myproject.dev` (like the good old days). But remeber you can run  only one container on 80 port at the same time.

Comment: Ouch! That was more evident than I thought, feel ashamed now. Thank you!

Comment: @sh4 No need to feel ashamed. I have spent so much time trying to figure this exact thing that is supposed to be so 'self-evident' that there seems to be no good documentation or a "Noob's guide" as such. So thank you for asking that and thanks to Bukharov for answering it although my server config didn't require the catch all line.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note, the nginx conf on projects generated by phpdocker.io will respond to any hostname, so you simply need to add the relevant entry on the hosts file.